# javascript - convert number to a float with precision of 2

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

I am using Javascript and need to convert a number like 0.009 into a number 0.90.

I am trying to do the below, but it only returns 0.9 : 
`parseFloat((testValue * 100).toFixed(2))`

For numbers like 0.0055, it is giving me 0.55, but for 0.009/0.008/0.007 etc, it is giving me 0.9/0.8/0.7 or in other words number with a precision of 1 after decimal.

How can I make it return 2 precision after decimal point? For eg, I want the code to return 0.90 for 0.009, 0.80 for 0.008 and so on..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't call `parseFloat()` after formatting the number with the number of digits you want. That converts it from a formatted string back to a number, and numbers don't have a specific precision.

Comment: Numbers always have the same precision, which is determined by the way they are stored; in Javascript, it is 53 bits of precision, translating to 15 to 17 digits in decimal, and are always shown without trailing zeroes in the fractional part. If you want to show a number in another precision, you have to use a string: `num.toFixed(2)` (without `parseFloat`, which turns it back into float, which will again have precision of 15-17, and not show trailing zeroes in the fractional part.)

Comment: Could I please get an example of the above?

Comment: ^^ this (Amadan's comment). Numbers are numbers, `4.0` is the same of `4.000` which is the same of `4.00000000`. How you decide to *write* them down is a different matter.

Comment: So if I do (testValue * 100).toFixed(2), it gives me the value I want with an additional trailing zero, but it is returned as string. I wish to return it as a number, hence am trying to do parseFloat() on the result. What am I missing here?

Comment: As a number, there's no difference between `.9` and `.90`.

Comment: Printing a number always omits trailing zeroes. That's why you need to use `toFixed()` when you're displaying it to get the desired precision.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I need to display it as 0.90 for special reasons. And I also need the value returned as a number, rather than a string.

Comment: So call `toFixed()` whenever you display it.

Comment: toFixed() returns the value as a string, not a number...
I need to return a number with 2 precision... Eg 0.009 should give me 0.90, not '0.90' -if that helps

Comment: "I need to display it as 0.90 for special reasons. And I also need the value returned as a number, rather than a string". You can't need both at the same time. It's like "I want to eat this chicken. Also, I want it as a pet." The two don't work together. Make up your mind. When you display it, make it into a string (you don't need numberhood for display). When you calculate with it, keep it as a number (you don't need zeroes for calculation). It _can't_ be a number and keep trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

Just call `toFixed(2)`, without calling `parseFloat()`. `parseFloat()` is converting the formatted number back into a floating point number, and they don't have different precisions.

```js
let num = .009;
console.log((num * 100).toFixed(2));
console.log(parseFloat((num * 100).toFixed(2)));
```

Comment: From your solution, If you set num = 1024.009; Your output will be 102400.90 and 102400.9 respectively. Which is incorrect, I guess.

Comment: The value for num can be any number, Your solution is only applicable for numbers below 0.

Comment: My solution treats all numbers the same. It multiplies by 100 and then shows the result with 2 decimal places, just like the question says. What do you think the output should be for `1024.009`?

Comment: According to your solution, 102400.90 and 102400.9. Just try checking it on the console.